# Localhost access is working but when i use Ipaddress access then it is not working - xampp

Tags: xampp

I installed XAMPP and I started the served. When I type "localhost" in the browser URL it is working fine. When I type my machine IP address where the XAMPP resides that is "172.31.1.3" it is not working.

Can any one help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

The Apache server needs to be told what ethernet devices to listen for connections. It's probably by default only listening on the localhost, you can add entries to so that it will also listen on 172.31.1.3.

Take a look at the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html).

You'll probably need to do the following:

- Stop the XAMPP server, if it is running already.
- Open the file `[XAMPP Installation Folder]/apache/conf/httpd.conf`.
- Search for the string *Listen 80 *(I'm assuming that your XAMPP was using the port 80.
- Otherwise, just search for the string 'Listen'). This is the port number which XAMPP uses.
- Change this 80 to 172.31.1.3:80.
- Now save and re-start XAMPP server and you are done.